# Unable to add a new row to the observablecollection listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, datacontext

In my project I have the following pages:

> Mainwindow.xaml
>
> Window1.xaml
>
> User.cs
>
> App.xaml

I declared the `Name` and `Age` property in `User.cs` and on `MainWindow.xaml` I made a `ObservableCollection` for a `ListBox`. `MainWindow` has a `Button Add`. When we click on the `Add button`. Then the `Window1.xaml` form is displayed. Which has two `TextBoxes` of name and age and a button (`ADD Name`). Now I want when we click on the `Add Name button` then the details in the both text boxes are attached to the `ObservableCollection` that is defined on the `Mainwindow.xaml.cs`.

Please suggest me want can I do:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnInit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string textA=textBox1.Text;
        int textB=Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        this.DataContext = new User(textA, textB);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User user = (User)(this.DataContext);
        new MainWindow().observableCollection.Add(user);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

now I ran this code  I am unable to get the values in the user object.

Comment: Probably because you are creating a new instance of your `MainWindow` class, adding a `user` to it, then it goes out of scope and destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not accessing the `MainWindow` CbservableCollection, you are creating a new `MainWindow`.

If this `Window1` is a dialog you have a few options

1. Pass the MainWindow into Window1 as its owner
2. Use the Window1 as a dialog and fetch the changes when it closes

personally I think the 2nd option is the best, but it depends how you are calling `Window1`

Example2:

MainWindow Class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> _myList = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set { _myList = value; }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new Window1();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MyCollection.Add(dialog.NewUser);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="405" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="TextA"  Margin="0,0,0,47" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,12" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="button1_Click_1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1 xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="119" Width="300" Name="UI">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewUser.TextA}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewUser.TextB}" />
        <Button Click="button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="90" Height="30" Content="Add" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Window1 code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private User _newUser = new User();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public User NewUser
    {
        get { return _newUser; }
        set { _newUser = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("NewUser"); }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

User Class

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _textA;
    private string _textB;

    public string TextA
    {
        get { return _textA; }
        set { _textA = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TextA"); }
    }

    public string TextB
    {
        get { return _textB; }
        set { _textB = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TextB"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this solution helped me alot, but  MyCollection.Add(dialog.NewUser); In this code the NewUser Property have the null values for both the TextA and TextB.

Comment: Thanks,this solution helped me alot,could you please tell me the concept that you used in:<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewUser.TextA}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewUser.TextB}" /> why you using the datacontext in stack panal...if don't use it then what will be happened.Thanks one again